# Accessing the Auth object in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am trying to access the auth object in angular2 using firebase but I have become confused. I can see the user auth credentials in the console but the auth variable seems to be null.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    title = 'app works!';

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {

    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => console.log(auth)); //nothing in the console

    console.log(this.af.auth); // shows AngularFireAuth object with user credentials but says it is private

  }
          login() {
                console.log("logging in...");
                this.af.auth.login({
                        provider: AuthProviders.Google,
                        method: AuthMethods.Popup,
                });
              }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="auth">You are logged in</div>
<div *ngIf="!auth">Please log in</div>
```

The `auth` variable appears to be null even though `console.log(this.af.auth);` is showing the user credentials and therefore only `Please log in` is displayed in the html.

Comment: have you called component login method and checked after it ?

Comment: I was in similar shoes before. This is why the community suggested for a documentation on managing auth state. See https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/343

Answer (score 1):

```
 this.af.auth.login(value, {provider:AuthProviders.Password, method:AuthMethods.Password}).then((success) =>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(success));
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

See the example 
https://github.com/Govinda-Wagle/Angular2-AngularFire-Blog/blob/master/src/app/Login/login.component.ts

Comment: Please read: [*Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/338149)